# MSBuild/WebDeploy - How to prevent it from deleting a folder and its contents

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, webdeploy

We're using TeamCity to automate MSBuild to use WebDeploy to push our application to our various servers.

For the most part, we've got this working, and great.  One snag, though: we've got a folder that holds uploads that we *don't* want to have deleted during the publication.

How do I tell WebDeploy, "I know that folder's not in the compiled application.  Ignore it.  Just leave it alone."

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321264/how-do-i-keep-msdeploy-from-deleting-extra-folders-in-my-project totally did what we needed.

Comment: You should answer your own question to help others :)

Comment: This other answer may help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23812739/114029

Answer (score 15):

If you're using the [dirPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207412%28WS.10%29.aspx), [filePath](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207414%28WS.10%29.aspx), or [contentPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569034%28WS.10%29.aspx) providers, you can specify the `DoNotDelete` rule to block deletions of files on the destination computer that do not exist on the source. The syntax to add to the command line would be `-enableRule:DoNotDelete`. For more information, see the provider articles mentioned and [Web Deploy Rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568992%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: How can i DoNotDelete a specific folder in the root of the app? skip is not working for me

Comment: What are providers?