# Remove additional files at destination in MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, msdeploy

When I build and deploy using Visual Studio, I can choose to 'remove additional files at destination'.

How can I do this with MSBuild? As the additional files will vary, I can't just use the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd15byf.aspx) and [RemoveDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyfz6ddb.aspx) tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a publish profile (.pubxml), I believe using this is analagous to checking the 'remove additional files at destination'

```
<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
```

Then referencing the Publish Profile in msbuild:

```
<MSBuild Projects="proj.csproj"
         Targets="WebPublish"
         Properties="VisualStudioVersion=11.0;
          Configuration=$(Configuration);
          PublishProfile=$(Configuration).pubxml;
          MSDeployServiceUrl=$(ServiceUrl);
          UserName=$(MSDeployUsername);
          Password=$(MSDeployPassword)"  />
```

If not using publish profile, I'd think just adding the SkipExtraFilesOnServer=False in the build task properties would do the trick.

Comment: Yes that's correct according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3321311/2874896)

Answer (score 0):

You pass another property to msbuild:

```
<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="MyProject.sln" Properties="...SkipExtraFilesOnServer=False..."/>
</Target>
```